# Rails query - search a field for an Array index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.35 / Ruby 1.87

If I have a Rails query:

```
test = Test.all
```

Say the table that "test" represents has a field called "color" like:

```
test[0].color = 'blue'
test[1].color = 'red'
```

How can I search the array to find out (say) the array index where the color field == 'orange'?

Bascially I just want to find 'orange' in the color field and get the index # of that index so I can use it to get the value of another field at the same index.  Like if test[3].color == 'orange' then I want that '3' index to grab test[3].name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't query to find the exact thing you're looking for and then reference the name directly? In Rails 2.3, something like this:

```
Test.find_by_color('orange').name
```

Would result in you getting the name of the test with the color orange.

Comment: Only in that I'm trying to avoid a hundred small queries going off matching this data against data from another db type where I can't create a single query.   I know I could just loop through the results to do this - just seemed like there should be fast way like ".index" but it doesn't seem to work like it would against a normal array.